# Macro not working properly: how to highlight entire rows if the direction is not matching the qty values

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Data Example from Excel]

I'm attempting to loop through my data and highlight the rows that have a direction value that do not match the values set forth by the numbers. Just for your knowledge, sell short means that you are selling stock you don't own. Sell long means that you are selling stocks you own. We are to assume that each of the securities start out with quantity 0. I'm posted an example of the data and my code. Thanks!

```
Sub TurnRed()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim qtyGHI As Integer
Dim qtyABC As Integer
Dim qtyDEF As Integer
Dim direction As String
qtyGHI = 0
qtyABC = 0
qtyDEF = 0

For counter = 2 To counter = 9
    direction = Cells(counter, "C").Value
    If Cells(counter, "E").Value = "GHI US" Then
        Select Case direction
            Case direction = "Buy"
                qtyGHI = qtyGHI + Cells(counter, "D").Value
            Case direction = "Sell_short"
                If qtyGHI - Range("Di").Value > 0 Then
                    Cells(counter, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Case direction = "Sell_long"
                If qtyGHI - Range("Di").Value < 0 Then
                    Cells(counter, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End Select
    ElseIf Cells(counter, "E").Value = "ABC US" Then
        Select Case direction
            Case "Buy"
                qtyABC = qtyABC + Cells(counter, "D").Value
            Case "Sell_short"
                If qtyABC - Range("Di").Value > 0 Then
                    Cells(counter, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Case "Sell_long"
                If qtyABC - Range("Di").Value < 0 Then
                    Cells(counter, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End Select
    ElseIf Cells(counter, "E").Value = "DEF US" Then
        Select Case direction
            Case direction = "Buy"
                qtyDEF = qtyDEF + Cells(counter, "D").Value
            Case direction = "Sell_short"
                If qtyDEF - Range("Di").Value > 0 Then
                    Cells(counter, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Case direction = "Sell_long"
                If qtyDEF - Range("Di").Value < 0 Then
                    Cells(counter, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End Select
    Next counter
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to let us know what the current result is and how that differs from the desired result.  Are you having a problem with a specific issue?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then show the data as [table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) not as image.

Comment: I'm getting a compile error "Case without select case"

Comment: Most of your case statements contain an `If` statement without an `End if` prior to the next statement

Comment: You assigned "Direction" as a "String" variable, it should be a "Range" variable. You have not defined the Variable "i", So your `Range("Di").Value` Should be `Range("D" & i).Value` or better change it to Cells(i, "D").Value` or even better `Cells(i, 4).Value`

Comment: Also they way you are using "qtyGHI", etc and the cell value in col D, will be the same value, you will never get a > or < condition. So, your rows will not be colored red.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not being clear; this is the best code, based on your data example, i could produce. It should give you a start.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim myNmbr As Long

    With ws
    lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'set up the last row

        For i = 2 To lr 'loop from row2 to the last row
            'the next line test the values in col3 and col5 and adjust the Variable myNmbr to the value in col4.
            'it will update the variable if the conditions match again
            If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Buy" And .Cells(i, 5).Value Like "GHI US" Then myNmbr = .Cells(i, 4).Value
            'the next line test the values in col3 and col5 and if match checks the cell in col4 against the Variable myNmbr
            If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Sell_Short" And .Cells(i, 5).Value Like "ABC US" And .Cells(i, 4).Value <> myNmbr Then
                'If the Value in col4, does not match the Variable myNmbr it colors the cells in the row from col1 to col7
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
            'the next line does the same test but for "Sell_Long" and "GHI US"
            If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Sell_Long" And .Cells(i, 5).Value Like "GHI US" And .Cells(i, 4).Value <> myNmbr Then
                'colors the range the same as above
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next i

    End With
```